# How news can be displayed as scrolling text?

Tags: newsfeed

I want to display news list as scrolling text(i.e. like marquee text) in my particular div.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I wanted to be apply news ticker on my website and for that I am thinking to apply above method. Any new ideas are welcome.

Comment: Ideas given in answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Idea

Read items from news list using any **CSOM** which can be **JSOM** or **REST API**

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('New List Name')/Items
```

For REST API help, you can check my following article.

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Now create **News Ticker** using those items. Check following jsfiddle links which can help you to create **News Ticker**, I believe.

http://jsfiddle.net/stevenchu/ezEtK/

https://jsfiddle.net/jackrugile/ZexrM/

http://jsfiddle.net/israelwebdev/YsSpY/8/